# Installation problems

Tags: mongodb

After a fresh install of mongodb following the instruction here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/index.html

I seem to have a problem:

```
ludo@aegir:~$ sudo service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-25 07:24:20 BST; 40min ago
  Process: 526 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 526 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 25 07:23:53 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Apr 25 07:24:20 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILUR
Apr 25 07:24:20 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 25 07:24:20 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Then when I try to run mongo I get :

```
ludo@aegir:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-04-25T08:08:10.146+0100 I NETWORK  [js] recv(): message msgLen 1347703880 is invalid. Min 16 Max: 48000000
2019-04-25T08:08:10.147+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

And from the mongodb logs :

```
ludo@aegir:~$ sudo tail -n 25 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log 
Apr 25 08:08:01 aegir CRON[4867]: (aegir) CMD (/usr/bin/env php /usr/local/bin/drush '@hostmaster' hosting-dispatch )
Apr 25 08:08:05 aegir php: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Apr 25 08:08:05 aegir CRON[4866]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user aegir
Apr 25 08:08:06 aegir sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 25 08:09:00 aegir systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Apr 25 08:09:00 aegir php7.2: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Apr 25 08:09:00 aegir php7.2: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Apr 25 08:09:00 aegir systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
Apr 25 08:09:01 aegir CRON[4941]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 25 08:09:01 aegir CRON[4942]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user aegir by (uid=0)
Apr 25 08:09:01 aegir CRON[4943]: (aegir) CMD (/usr/bin/env php /usr/local/bin/drush '@hostmaster' hosting-dispatch )
Apr 25 08:09:01 aegir CRON[4945]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Apr 25 08:09:01 aegir CRON[4941]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 25 08:09:05 aegir php: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Apr 25 08:09:05 aegir CRON[4942]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user aegir
Apr 25 08:10:01 aegir CRON[4964]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user aegir by (uid=0)
Apr 25 08:10:01 aegir CRON[4965]: (aegir) CMD (/usr/bin/env php /usr/local/bin/drush '@hostmaster' hosting-dispatch )
Apr 25 08:10:04 aegir php: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Apr 25 08:10:04 aegir CRON[4964]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user aegir
Apr 25 08:11:01 aegir CRON[4986]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user aegir by (uid=0)
Apr 25 08:11:01 aegir CRON[4987]: (aegir) CMD (/usr/bin/env php /usr/local/bin/drush '@hostmaster' hosting-dispatch )
Apr 25 08:11:05 aegir php: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
Apr 25 08:11:05 aegir CRON[4986]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user aegir
Apr 25 08:11:09 aegir sudo:     ludo : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/ludo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -n 25 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
Apr 25 08:11:09 aegir sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

How to go about finding the problem?

After entering ludo@aegir:~$ sudo service mongod start
Then issuing sudo systemctl status mongod
The output is:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-25 11:49:09 BST; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 2128 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited
 Main PID: 2128 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 25 11:49:09 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Apr 25 11:49:09 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited,
Apr 25 11:49:09 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed 
Apr 25 11:49:09 aegir.local.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result '
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: Please post a few more details from mongod log(look for any errors or failures). The log information posted in the question is not enough to figure out the problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Installation problems

As I am able to see in your shell command you have try to start mongod server through the command such as

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/index.html) Issue the following command to start [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod):

```
sudo service mongod start
```

If you installed via the package manager, the **`data`** directory `/var/lib/mongodb` and the **`log`** directory `/var/log/mongodb` are created during the installation.

Verify that the mongod process has started successfully by checking the contents of the log file at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log for a line reading

```
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but: